# why the new user created with password is not asking for the password

Tags: database, postgresql, console, su

I am a new user in Postgres i am following this tutorial https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First_steps
i want to create a new user with the password for that i am following these steps

```
sudo -i -u postgres
postgres@sarawaheed:~$ psql
psql (9.3.9)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE USER sara PASSWORD 'sara';
CREATE ROLE
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA test TO sara;
GRANT
/q
```

then i open a new terminal and typed 
s

```
sudo -i -u sara
sara@sarawaheed:~$ psql
psql (9.3.9)
Type "help" for help.

sara=>
```

so i have two questions 
One why with this command it does ask for a password `sudo -i -u sara` 
Second with this command     `su - sara` it asks for a password but when i typed the password which in my case is sara why is it not accepting

```
   su - sara
    Password: 
    su: Authentication failure
```

how do i assure that my user is created with password ,please help me

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not ask for a password if the connection type you're using is configured as trusted.

See the [pg_hba.conf file documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Comment: so how do i confirm that user will get acces to db only after giving password ?